# Composite key that includes a foreign key

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table that uses a composite key as its primary key.
I am having trouble assigning the second value in the composite key, as it is a foreign key in a different table. Here is an example.

```
create table Table1
(Table1ID NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (Table1ID));

create table Table2
(Table2ID NVARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT Table2ID_Table1ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (Table2ID, Table1ID)); <---- Here
```

In the second table I'm trying to make the primary key include the primary key from table1. Do I need to include something like `REFERENCES Table1(Table1ID));` ?

Also, what would be the correct way to insert data into table2 for the composite key? `insert into Table2 values ('101, 1001', .... );` ?

Cheers.

Comment: The field must be in the table before any constraint on the table can include it!

Comment: I see, so it's impossible to inherit an entity from another table to use for a composite key?

Comment: You should include your rdbms `Sql Server`, `Oracle`, etc Show us what have you try and what error you have. Because at first look seem ok. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PetShopBoys, by your naming convention you've called the first column of TABLE2 TABLE2ID, well is it an ID column for TABLE2 or not?  If it is, that is your primary key.  Take a look at this for a discussion of compound keys: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

Comment: @RobertDupuy The reason for this is I have items going into this table where Table2ID has duplicates. I thought this might be a possible way to store them in the table by changing the primary key to a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreign key in your composite primary key but be aware you will create a 1-to-1 mapping and table B will be dependent on table A and so to preserve referential integrity the row/ID in table A must already exist before attempting to insert into table B who uses A's primary key as foreign key in it's primary key and to reflect this design choice I have added an `ON DELETE` clause to the solution.

Without too much modification you can use this MySQL solution to fit your DMBS of choice as you did not specify what you were using.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    id   int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ..
);

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
     id             int NOT NULL,
     tableA_id      int NOT NULL,
     ...
     FOREIGN KEY (tableA_id) REFERENCES TableA(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     PRIMARY KEY(id, tableA_id)
);
```